# Currency Convertor

Tags: currency

How Convert USD to INR ( base currency) in magento?.
I tried to below code , but not working.

```
$amt=1000;
Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amt, 'USD', 'INR');
```

But its work on `Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amt, 'INR', 'USD');`

Comment: this price in inr

Comment: No, Price in USD. i need to current currency (USD) to Base currency ( INR )

Comment: clear cache.....

Comment: is this price 1000 in USD?

Comment: yes , USD Price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `convert   one price currency price to  base currency`.

because `magento did not calculate base currency rate  from  other current rate`.

Magento `define a price  in BASE currency which will convert  using rate  for other currency`

Magento `is calculate other price  from base Currency`

Please got see Mage_Directory_Model_Currency class on function

```
 public function convert($price, $toCurrency=null)
    {
        if (is_null($toCurrency)) {
            return $price;
        }
        elseif ($rate = $this->getRate($toCurrency)) {
            return $price*$rate;
        }

        throw new Exception(Mage::helper('directory')->__('Undefined rate from "%s-%s".', $this->getCode(), $toCurrency->getCode()));
    }
```

Here `show that you can not get base currency from other currency`

That means that 
you code format is

**Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amt, 'baseCurrecy', 'your currency');**

```
revise it not possible using this function
```

**Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amt, 'your currency', 'baseCurrecy');**

Comment: Is it possible any other way to convert?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to convert a price from current currency to base currency using `Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($amt, 'USD', 'INR')` method because Magento doesn't find the row with "currentCurrency"=>"baseCurrency" relation in the *directory_currency_rate* table.

To solve this issue you can simply do a division of the price by "baseCurrency"=>"currentCurrency" rate.

How could you get "baseCurrency"=>"currentCurrency" rate and solve your issue?
In this way:

```
// the price
$amt=1000;
// Base Currency ('INR')
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
// Current Currency ('USD')
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

// Allowed currencies
$allowedCurrencies = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
$rates = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->getCurrencyRates($baseCurrencyCode, array_values($allowedCurrencies));
// the price converted
$amt= $amt/$rates[$currentCurrencyCode];
```

Comment: Thanks Wapone for the solution!